# msysgit and git-cheetah having issues on winXP with "Git Bash" context menu

Tags: git, msysgit

I've installed msysgit version 1.8.0 on Windows XP and I chose to use the plugin "advanced" version for the context menu.  If i start up git bash from the shortcut icon, it starts up fine.  But if I use the right click context menu, I got the following errors:

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.8.0-preview20121022)

Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
sh: /bin/stty: No such file or directory 
sh: /bin/stty: No such file or directory
sh: hostname: command not found
sh: unalias: cm: not found
:Desktop/2 part Auth/GoogleAuth>
```

I used the same version on my home windows 7 machine and had no issues at all.

Any clues?

Thanks,
Justin